# No puedo visualizar ciertos objetos en delphi

Tags: delphi

Hola estoy editando una pequeña aplicación grafica para juntar diferentes ficheros en delphi pero me pasa algo extraño. La aplicación tiene la siguiente apariencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la compilo y ejecuto de repente de desaparecen los objetos de las esquina y no se porque:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui una foto de las caracteristicas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esos 'objetos en la esquina' son **componentes** de Delphi, **no** controles.

- Un control es todo aquel elemento gráfico potencialmente visible (aunque esté oculto) en tu aplicación, capaz de reacionar ante acciones del usuario (clicks del ratón, pulsaciones de teclas, ... ).
  La ventana de tu aplicación es un control.
- Los componentes son elementos **no** gráficos usados *en la parte de atras* de tu aplicación; proporcionan funcionalidad. Son instancias de clases, como cualquier otra instancia que uses en tu programa.

Técnicamente, los **componentes** proporcionan cierta funcionalidad, como información en tiempo de ejecución sobre su tipo y funciones internas, haciendo que sea fácil trabajar con ellos. **No** soportan interacción directa con el usuario, ni se pueden mostrar en pantalla.

Los controles, por su parte, **heredan** de los componentes; un control *es un* componente. Permiten trabajar con ellos igual de fácil que con componentes, y, **ademas**, **pueden** ser mostrados en pantalla e interactuar con el usuario. Técnicamente, los controles *responden a eventos* del sistema, entre ellos el *redibujado*.

Entonces, ¿ porqué se muestran ? Pues porque, **durante el desarrollo** de tu aplicación, Delphi *aprovecha* esa funcionalidad que ofrecen los **componentes** para permitir definir, de forma grafica (mediante su ventana de propiedades) los atributos *iniciales* del componente, para ahorrarte a tí el hacerlo *a mano* en tu código (cosa que, por otra parte, siempre puedes hacer).

Al no ser **controles**, no tienen representación visual y tu aplicación, durante su **ejecución**, no muestra nada referente a ellos.

¿ Como se usan ? pués depende del **componente**. Algunos, como el 'TSaveDialog', tienen el método 'execute'; otros, como el 'TTimer', se ejecutan mientras estén activos y tengan una propiedad 'OnTimer' válida.

Por último, los **componentes**, durante su trabajo normal, pueden mostrar ciertos **controles**. El 'TSaveDialog' mostrará un diálogo para seleccionar archivos; pero el diálogo en si no es el **componente**, es un ente independiente, creado y ejecutado por el primero.